# how to pause and resume a kotlin coroutine when touching a view?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

In my app I want to display a splash screen and after 4 seconds go to HomeActivity. However, I would like to pause the execution by touching imageview `imageSplash` and resume when releasing. How to do this?

```kotlin
GlobalScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.Main) {
   imageSplash.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
      when(motionEvent.action) {
          MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> true
          MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> true
          else -> false
      }
   }
   
   delay(4000)
   val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
   startActivity(intent)
   finish()
}
```

Comment: There's no magical mechanism that will do that. You can use a boolean flag and check it many times in the code you want to be able to pause. But, if it's doing some network ops, that cannot be paused because the execution happens on a remote server.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but hopefully it will help.

As mentioned by @I.Step, coroutines do not offer functionality for pausing and resuming so, in this case, a simple flag like `var isPaused: Boolean` could work. You'll just need to check it while the coroutine is running.

Example:

```kotlin
private var isPaused = false

GlobalScope.launch(...) {
    while (isActive)
    {
        if (!isPaused)
        {
            // do your work here
        }
    }
}

fun pause()
{
    isPaused = true
}

fun resume()
{
    isPaused = false
}
```

Comment: I would add a delay() after 'if', to not consume a lot o pc and be able to cancel the Job, and change to be thread safe: "private var isPaused = false" to private var isPaused = AtomicBoolean(false)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin coroutine is of a type kotlinx.coroutines.Job.
That class does not have methods to pause or resume a job.

Alternatively:

You need to write a logic with 2 coroutines.
One that starts HomeActivity after 4 seconds.
Second that listens ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP motion events. On ACTION_DOWN you cancel the first coroutine Job, and after ACTION_UP (after N seconds) you show HomeActivity from a second coroutine.